# Trouble with Promises and Callbacks in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise

I am trying to get a list of objects out of an S3 bucket and when I have a list of objects I would like to generate pre-signed URLs for these objects. The only way I could figure out how to do this was to use nested callback functions like so:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
console.log('processing event: %j', event);

const bucket = process.env['s3_bucket'];
if (!bucket) {
    callback(new Error("s3 bucket not set"));
}

const deviceId = event['deviceId'];

const params = getListObjectsParams(deviceId, bucket);
let count = 0;

await s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) callback("Error getting image list: " + err);
    else {
        data.Contents.forEach(function (image) {
            count = count + 1;
            const objectParams = getObjectParams(bucket, image.Key);
            s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', objectParams, function (err, url) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.log(err);
                    //TODO: log error getting pre signed url
                } else {
                    images.push(url);
                }
            });

        });
    }
});

callback(null, images);
```

};

I am having some trouble returning the images array as the function is completing before the calls to listObjectsV2 and each of the getSignedUrl complete. Here are my questions.

1. How do I get the execution to wait for promises to complete before completing executing the function?
2. If there a better way to layout this block of code, nesting callbacks look messy :(

Comment: Your code shows use of plain callbacks and indicate no use of promises at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the execution to wait for promises to complete before completing executing the function?

Inside an `async` function, put `await` in front of a promise.

You've done the first two of those, but `s3.listObjectsV2` **doesn't return a promise**.

If you want to use `await` with it then you must [convert the existing callback API to a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score 1):

The AWS JavaScript SDK natively supports promises. Instead of this:

```
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
    // do something with data here in the callback
});
```

write this:

```
const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
// do something with data here
```

Note that `await` may only be used in an `async` function. If you aren't in an async function then you can fabricate one as follows (an immediately invoked async arrow function):

```
(async () => {
    const data = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
    // do something with data here
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on .promise() for listObjectsV2. That was super useful. Turns out they do not have a .promise() call for getSignedUrls (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1008)

Comment: You can promisify any callback-style async function.

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing.